# How to resolve BSoD error message?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I always turn my work computer off at the end of the business day. I do this to bolster PC health and wellness. Sometimes, however, I come back the next day, turn it on, and it displays the Blue Screen of Death screen:

Here are details specific to my error (retrieved by BlueScreenView downloaded utility, complements of Cory M.)

> 050818-33243-01.dmp   5/8/2018 6:55:53
>   AM    DRIVER_CORRUPTED_MMPOOL 0x000000d0  00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   nwifi.sys   nwifi.sys+3aea                  x64 ntoskrnl.exe+a4470                  C:\Windows\Minidump\050818-33243-01.dmp 8   15  7601    317,608 5/8/2018 6:58:00 AM

It transitions shortly to the boot choice screen, and I choose "Start Windows normally". This process is repeated a few times; then finally it loads the OS and I can sign in with my credentials and proceed with business as usual. It baffles me that I am being told that "A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer" when I MANUALLY OPT TO SHUT DOWN MY COMPUTER. So why am I getting this message? How do I make it stop?

System Info: Alienware, Windows 7 Professional

[image]

Comment: The BSOD is happening on boot. Whether it is rebooting because you turned it off last night or for some completely different reason has nothing to do with it. It is booting...It has a problem...It Blue Screens...

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xea--thread-stuck-in-device-driver This is what Microsoft reports for your BSOD issue. As they state: "Frequently, this is the result of a bad video card or a bad display driver"

Comment: @EBGreen The first time the screen shows, however, I do not understand how the message "A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer" is a true statement--Seeing as how Windows was shut down on my own accord.

Comment: You turn off the computer - The next morning you turn on the computer - Windows immediately detects a problem and shuts down - Windows tells you it shut the machine down because it did...

Comment: @SarahSchnoor Windows says this because it shut down in such a way that was not normal. You did start a shutdown but windows did not FINISH shutting down before it crashed thus windows shut it self down to prevent damage.

Comment: Just so you know ALL BSOD messages (something prevented windows from shutting down normally) are sent correctly.

Comment: analyze the [C:\Windows\Minidump\050818-33243-01.dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Answer (score 0):

This BSOD is caused by a device driver error. when you go to restart/shutdown windows sends a signal to all the programs running to shutdown. A driver on your system is not shutting down in time thus causing windows to throw a BSOD.

This is very common for GPU/Audio drivers to cause this.

Since this is a work computer I would recommend you give this to your IT department and have them fix it because its likely you dont have access to install drivers or make the needed changes to fix this issue.

**EDIT 1:**

Wishing to be the best community member I can below are the instructions to find the error code for the BSOD you are receiving

1. Download bluescreenview (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)
2. Open and run bluescreenview
3. The program will populate with all the BSOD mini-dumps that you have on your system
4. Select the one with the most recent date
5. If possible post a screenshot with the view you have of bluescreenview or post the bug check string, bug check code, and all the parameters plus any file that is listed.

Comment: Perhaps I should delete this post. I did not realize there are various error codes that would come with the BSoD. I just used a picture as an example. I am not sure the exact error code that comes with it. It may be the 0000000, or it may not. I will take a picture of it the next time I see it. Then I will refine the question. Is there a way I can take down the question without losing it on my own account?

Comment: @SarahSchnoor - Edit your question to include the error code.  However, the problem is caused by a display driver, since you are using Windows 7.  You should contact your IT Administrator for help.

Comment: also i am technically the IT admin (mostly bc we dont have one and i booted in safemode and just added myself to the list of admin users). I am an IT major so this isnt the worst thing  @_@

Comment: Asking help in private is unfair to everyone that has this problem, in order to get it reopened, the question should be clarified and improved.  A generic screenshot of a BSOD won’t help us identify the cause of your problem.  Proper formatting is critical in making a question readable, clear, and answerable